# Find-Replace Multiple Occurrences of a string and append iterating number

Tags: regex, perl

How can I iterate over the code of an html file and find certain recurring text and then append a word and and iterating number to it.

```
So: 
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable -->
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable -->
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable -->   
etc...                    

Becomes :
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable Event=1 -->
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable Event=2 -->
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable Event=3 -->
etc...
```

I have tried PERL thinking it would be the easiest/fastest and went to jQuery and then back to PERL.

It seems simple enough to find/replace many ways with REGEX and return an array of the occurrences, but getting the iterating variable tacked on proves to be more of a challenge.

Latest Example of what I have tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# Open input file 
open INPUTFILE, "<", $ARGV[0] or die $!;
# Open output file in write mode
open OUTPUTFILE, ">", $ARGV[1] or die $!;

# Read the input file line by line
while (<INPUTFILE>) {
  my @matches = ($_ =~ m/TemplateBeginEditable/g);
  ### what do I do ith matches array? ###
  $_ =~ s/TemplateBeginEditable/TemplateBeginEditable Event=/g;
  print OUTPUTFILE $_; 

}


close INPUTFILE;
close OUTPUTFILE;
```

Comment: "I have tried PERL thinking it would be the easiest/fastest and went to jQuery and then back to PERL." What exactly are you editing that either Perl or jQuery would be an option? Are you using a Perl templating tool like Template Toolkit?

Comment: `perl -lpi.bkp -e's/TemplateBeginEditable/"$& Event=" . ++$i/ge' file.html` is a simple one-liner to do it.  But if this is for a more involved project, of which this is only one small part, you should expand it into a more fully realized program, with `strict` and `warnings` enabled, at a minimum.

Comment: I am unfortunately, and begrudgingly using a Dreamweaver template/Adobe Contribute "CMS" system. I just did not want to manually  do find/replace+ for 200 editable regions. So the code would not live in production. The one- liner above is similar and likely as effective as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform a replacement, you don't need to match the pattern before, you can directly perform the replacement. Example with your code:

```
while (<INPUTFILE>) {
    s/TemplateBeginEditable/TemplateBeginEditable Event=/g;
    print OUTPUTFILE $_; 
}
```

Now to add a counter incremented at each replacement, you can put a piece of code in the pattern itself using this syntax:

```
my $i;

while (<INPUTFILE>) {
    s/TemplateBeginEditable(?{ ++$i })/TemplateBeginEditable Event=$i/g;
    print OUTPUTFILE $_; 
}
```

To make it shorter you can use the `\K` feature to change the start of the match result:

```
while (<INPUTFILE>) {
    s/TemplateBeginEditable\K(?{ ++$i })/ Event=$i/g;
    print OUTPUTFILE $_; 
}
```

Or with a one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/TemplateBeginEditable\K(?{++$i})/ Event=$i/g' file > output
```

Comment: In the second and third examples here, for "my $i", don't I have to declare  $i=1, before I can add 1 to it at each iteration?

Comment: @JohnnyP: No you don't need, because `$i` is incremented *(with `++$i`)* before being used in the replacement. Writing `$i=0` is useless too.

Comment: This one liner works for my purposes. Although I do not fully understand the K-switch, even after Googling. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnnyP: The `\K` only changes the position where starts the whole match. example for the string "abcb": `s/a\Kb/x/g` returns "axcb" *("ab" is found but only the part starting after `\K` is returned, and only b is replaced)*

Answer (score 1):

If you have `awk` available, and the target text only occurs at most once per line, then Perl is overkill I think:

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=1}{n+=sub("TemplateBeginEditable","& Event="n)}1'
```

Some explanation: The `sub` function returns the number of substitutions performed (0 or 1); the `&` means "whatever matched"; `"..."n` is string concatenation (no operator in awk); the `1` is a "true" condition that invokes the default "action" of `{print}`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my one-liner in the comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = shift or die "Usage: $0 <filename>\n";

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Cannot open $file: $!\n";
open my $ofh, '>', "$file.modified" or die "Cannot open $file.modified: $!\n";

my $i = 1;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
   if ($line =~ s/TemplateBeginEditable/$& Event=$i/) {
      $i++;
   }
   print $ofh $line;
}

__END__
```

Note that this assumes you will never have more than one instance of your desired text on a single line, as shown in your sample input.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do:

```
local $/=undef;
my $content = <FH>;
my $x = 0;
$content =~ s/(My expected pattern)/$1 . " time=" . (++$x)/ge;
```